# Update shape and save the new values in json

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, shapes, auto-update

So far, I changed the values with a prompt box... Now I need, that the changes are def. and that means they change also in the json file. As add. the shape should be update after you change the value in the prompt box. My code looks like this:

```
var leength = INTERSECTED.parent.children[0].geometry.vertices.length / 2;
                    for (var pu = 0; pu < leength; pu++) {
                        var mesx = INTERSECTED.parent.children[0].geometry.vertices[pu].x;
                        var mesy = INTERSECTED.parent.children[0].geometry.vertices[pu].y;

                        //  INTERSECTED.parent.children[0].name = namefloe[0];

                        var showx = prompt("Usage: Business  Punkt x" + (pu + 1), mesx);
                        var showy = prompt("Usage: Business  Punkt y" + (pu + 1), mesy);

                        if (prompt != null) {
                            alert(" Punkt x" + (pu + 1) + " : " + showx + " Punkt y" + (pu + 1) + " : " + showy);
                        }
                        INTERSECTED.parent.children[0].geometry.vertices[pu].x = showx;
                        INTERSECTED.parent.children[0].geometry.vertices[pu].y = showy;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To autoupdate the values,you should add that the vertices have been changed.

```
INTERSECTED.parent.children[0].geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
```

Comment: incl.       'INTERSECTED.parent.children[0].geometry.dynamic = true;'